# Algorithm to find record in a log structured file system

Tags: algorithm, logging, data-structures, filesystems

I have a log of records. Each record has a ID and Timestamp. New records get appended to the log with monotonically increasing ID, even though there can be deletion of the records in between.

The problem is - If you are given a timestamp T1, provide an efficient algorithm to determine the log record which has timestamp = Ceil(T1).

Points to note. Log can be very big with millions of records. There can be missing records because of record deletion.

Example: If log record = (ID, Timestamp), then log can be shown like this:

(1, 10), (2, 11), (5, 15), (8,18), (9, 19), (10, 20)

Find ID of the record with min timestamp greater or equal to 17.

Answer is 8.

Find ID of the record with min timestamp greater or equal to 11.

Answer is 2.

Find ID of the record with min timestamp greater or equal to 22.

Answer is Nil

Find ID of the record with min timestamp greater or equal to 5.

Answer is 1

I have come up with simple data-structures to solve this problem.

```html
/* index:    0  1   2   3   4  5  6   7   8  9  10   11   12  */

int ids[]=     {1,  2,            6,  7,        10,  11,  12};
int map[]=  {0, 1,  1,  0,  0, 0, 1,  1,  0, 0, 1,   1,   1};
int time[]= {0, 10, 20, 0,  0, 0, 60, 70, 0, 0, 100, 110, 120};
int start= 1, end = 12;  // this is known to us.
```

ids[] is list of all the IDs. Given that this list can be millions, we cannot index this list in an array. So in the above example, IDs 3, 4, 5, 8, 9 are missing. But the list is in increasing order.

map[] is the bitmap which can tell you if given ID is present or not. It is a cheap operation.

time[] is the timestamp array for each of the IDs present. Remember to assume that getting timestamp is actually expensive operation.

Also there is no co-relation between ID's and timestamp value. Instead of 10, 20, etc it could be anything like 1133, 2987..and so on. but in increasing order.

You need to fill up this function:

```html
int
find_ceil_id(int timestamp) 
{
  .....
  ....
  return(id)
}
```

Comment: min id when timestamp is greater than or **equal** to 20 should be 10, right?

Comment: You are right. for 20, it will give 10, but for 22, answer is Nil

Comment: From what you have edited in  your original post, it now looks like the problem is searching through a memory array, rather than a file system log.  Entirely different search problems.  And the little bit of made up data simply won't cut it.  What makes for a good search algorithm depends on the data, a good programmer will want a good look at real data.  And are you doing this for a real job, or just "quizzing" us in SO for fun?

Comment: I want help from folks around here and this is a real problem I am facing.  I think the data that i provided is correct. If I solve this, then actual problem can also be solved. Two assumptions here: time[ID] is *EXPENSIVE*, and you cannot index into ID[].

Comment: Ok, I will be happy to work with you on this then.  Question, will this function persist from one search to another?  That is, does this function get called multiple times within a single execution of the overall program, or does it get called, it gives its results and the program ends?

Comment: Didnt understand why that would matter. But this function can be called again, but by then the all the three sets would have changed, some id got deleted, so dont exist in map anymore, which can change start. Some would get added towards the end because they increase everytime a new one gets added, so end can also change.

Comment: I have edited my answer to have the code that I think will do the job for you.

Comment: We cannot store IDs in the array. Sorry for the confusion. There can be millions of IDs so putting them in array is not feasible.  I showed them in the array to give an example. We only know the lowest and the highest ID present, ie start and end. We have a map which which will tell you if the ID is present or not.  If you find the middle one using binary search, you cannot do ids[checkIndex], because that might not exist. Do you think I should remove IDs[] array from my example to make it clear? Again sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I have made changes in the code that should cover what you said.  As far as hitting the TimeStamps, this is still a log2(N), so at most 30 hits for over a billion records.  The code never looks at id's because the id is just the index into the map.  The code does scan through the map.  With that being in memory, that should be ok.  In my vague recollections of assembly, I halfway remember a mask type operation that would do this kind of scanning faster, but I don't have the time to work that out.  It is possible this code has some boundary issues to work out.  I leave that to you as well.

Comment: I think this will work fine. But given a timestamp greater than last ID has returns the highest ID, which is incorrect. Also initial low and high  are already given. The code also doesnt work with the case where there are only two IDs present one low and other high. As you said there might be some boundary conditions issue, I think that is fine. But I was thinking if we could improve the search for "presence "  by using another binary search. Suppose there are only two IDs and their difference is in millions, then we are unnecessary going through map linearly?

Comment: You are correct about the boundary issues you mention.  They are the kind of details that I just do not have time to get down into.  There is no way to do a binary search through a list of zero values, so if your map is the way it is, the only way I can think of is a linear search, except that there should be a bit operation that will be better, but I would have to research that, and again, I don't have the time.  If it is possible to change the nature of the map, as it is built, then there are a number of ways to easily improve on this, but it would depend on the data and memory storage limit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this function was being kept in memory between searches, we could take advantage of previous searches to narrow down future searches.  If getting to the timestamps is expensive, then that could be a very significant improvement.  But if they are already in memory in the array you have in your post, then that is mostly a moot point.
Assuming that timestamps are unique, I would start with this for a solution:

```
int FindFirstNonZero(int startIdx)
{
    int myIdx=startIdx;
    while (map[myIdx] == 0)
    {
        myIdx++;
    }
    return(myIdx);
}

int FindLastNonZero(int startIdx)
{
    int myIdx=startIdx;
    while (map[myIdx] == 0)
    {
        myIdx--;
    }
    return(myIdx);
}

int find_ceil_id(int timestamp) 
{
    int low=FindFirstNonZero(0);
    int high=FindLastNonZero(map.count -1);
    int checkIndex = FindLastNonZero((low + high)/2);
    int checkTime;

    while (low < FindLastNonZero(high - 1))
    {
        checkTime = time[checkIndex];
        if (checkTime >= timestamp) {
            high = checkIndex;
        } else {
            low = checkIndex;
        }
        checkIndex = FindLastNonZero((low+high) / 2);
        if (checkIndex == low) {
            checkIndex = FindFirstNonZero(low+1);
        }
    }
    return (high);
}
```

From some of your comments, it seems that the timestamps can repeat.  Is that so?  If so, it would require a minor change to the above... Never mind, made the change and it even made the code simpler.

This is a basic binary search and it will find the right element in log2(N) tries, N being the size of the array of ID's.  So for just over a million entries in the ID array, it would only need to examine 20 of them to get at the right one.  For just over a billion entries, it would only need to examine 30.

I am not compiling and testing the code, that's up to you.  But it should work.

Comment: Gilchrist. The problem with your solution is that you are assuming a correlation between id and timestamp. Unfortunately there is not. It could be that thousands of the records have the same timestamp if the logging is too fast.

Comment: But over a longer time, would it average out?  It doesn't have to be a perfect, unfailing correlation because you will apply a different search after that to get from there to the actual node.  But if that still is not workable, I'd just go with a binary search, but refine it by keeping an in-memory table of nodes that gets you in the vicinity before you start hitting the file system.  If that is possible.  It's really hard to advise on something like this without a real look at the data and all the other variables that would affect a search algorithm.